# Can a device like chromecast degrade over time?

Tags: wifi, hardware, chromecast

I'm having trouble connecting to my chromecast in any apps. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it just won't work. I can see that it is connected to my WiFi network and I've read the very helpful answers at [chromecast-doesnt-show-up.](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/chromecast-doesnt-show-up) After many resets and hours of fighting with my chromecast, I am wondering, would buying a new chromecast help my problems? It is a few years old, but I can't think what parts would degrade over time in a chromecast.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the power suply? Sometimes if it's getting old it could be providing insufficient power... especially if you have another compatible supply lying around, requires no investment to try it out

Comment: @anonymous2 I'll have to try that.

Comment: As a point of reference, I have one of the very first batch of Chromecast ever shipped stuck in the back of my TV at the moment and have no problems with it (I happily watched Shang Chi and the legend of the ten rings on it this evening)

Comment: Electronics can fail over time, especially due to heat, but possibly also due to dust. Make sure it is in relatively well ventilated place and clean it. But usually such failures would more likely be permanent rather than intermittent. It is more likely to be a software or network issue IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be interference of signals in your wifi/zigbee network that builds up with time, when new devices added or some devices select the same channel.

I also experienced problems connecting to Chromecast and ended up connecting the Chromecast to my router by wire using Cat5 networking cable. Moving to the wired connection improved reliability a lot, I don't even remember when I reset the Chromecast after that.

There's a special power supply for Chromecast sold by Google that has RG-45 socket and provides not just power but   ethernet via USB https://store.google.com/us/product/chromecast_ethernet_adapter_gen_2